# Regex Pattern Matching -a substring in words in CSV File

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching

```
'Neighborhood,eattend10,eattend11,eattend12,eattend13,mattend10,mattend11,mattend12,mattend13,
hsattend10,hsattend11,hsattend12,hsattend13,eenrol11,eenrol12,eenrol13,menrol11,menrol12,
menrol13,hsenrol11,hsenrol12,hsenrol13,aastud10,aastud11,aastud12,aastud13,wstud10,wstud11,
wstud12,wstud13,hstud10,hstud11,hstud12,hstud13,abse10,abse11,abse12,abse13,absmd10,absmd11,
absmd12,absmd13,abshs10,abshs11,abshs12,abshs13,susp10,susp11,susp12,susp13,farms10,farms11,
farms12,farms13,sped10,sped11,sped12,sped13,ready11,ready12,ready13,math310,math311,math312,
math313,read310,read311,read312,read313,math510,math511,math512,math513,read510,read511,read512,
read513,math810,math811,math812,math813,read810,read811,read812,read813,hsaeng10,hsaeng11,
hsaeng12,hsaeng13,hsabio10,hsabio11,hsabio12,hsabio13,hsagov10,hsagov11,hsagov13,hsaalg10,
hsaalg11,hsaalg12,hsaalg13,drop10,drop11,drop12,drop13,compl10,compl11,compl12,compl13,
sclsw11,sclsw12,sclsw13,sclemp13\
```

I have this data set. I need to know how many `drop` words are there and print them.

Or similarly for any word like `mattend` and print those.

I tried using `findall` but I think that's not correct

I assume we can use `re.search` or `re.match`.
How can I do it in RegEx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `len()` on `re.findall()` to get the length of the returned list:

```
import re
with open('example.csv') as f:
  data = f.read().strip()
print(len(re.findall('drop',data)))
```

Comment: Thanks but it displays only the substring matched.  I want to print the strings as well, ```drop13,drop12,drop23``` as such and here's how I tried to do it from the above answer , ```re.findall("drop\d*", str)``` but I'm getting the error ```expected string or bytes-like object``` . Would you mind rectifying it ?

Comment: @kirtipurohit if then use a raw string `re.findall(r'drop\d*', str)` and please avoid `str` as variable name

Answer (score 1):

I think `re.findall` should be correct.
From python re module documentation:

Search:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where this regular expression produces a match, and return a corresponding match object.

Match:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match this regular expression, return a corresponding match object.

Findall:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

I tried it on your example and it worked for me:
`re.findall("drop", str)`

If you want to see digits after it you can try something like:
`re.findall("drop\d*", str)`

If you want to count the words you can use:
`len(re.findall("drop\d*", str))`

Comment: I am getting an error :  expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: ```with open('exg.csv','r') as file:
    data=file.read().split(',')  ```                                        I converted all those csv datatypes into string types but the error still persists